# How to get the result of a Access Query in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to do a query in an access db and then get this query result and insert into a Excel sheet, but nothing I do work. This is my code

```
Sub Analise()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Sheets("Plan1").Range("A2:A23").Select
    For Each Regra In Selection
        If Regra = "MYRULE" Then
            sSQL = "SELECT ITEM !, ITEM2 FROM base WHERE NomeRegra = ""'MyValue'"" "
            MyConn = "MyPath\base.mdb"
            Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
            With cnn
                .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
                .Open MyConn
            End With
            Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

            rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer

            rst.Open Source:=sSQL, ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=AdForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText

            Sheets("Plan1").Range("D1:E1") = Array("Field1", "Field2")

            Range("D2:E100000").CopyFromRecordset rst

            rst.Close
            cnn.Close
        End If

    Next Regra
```

Comment: See how to ask a [mcve]

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246335

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MS Query in Excel using your Access file as the DB?  From the data tab in Excel,

'Get External Data' 'From Other Sources' dropdown and then 'From MS Query'

Select MS Access Database and then find your file.  When the Query Wizard pop up appears, hit cancel and then 'Yes' to continue editing in MS Query.  If you'd rather write the SQL yourself, you can press the sql button, but the language is a little different than Access.  It might take some playing around, but MS query can be a very powerful tool.